# Increment in both side in C

Tags: c++, post-increment

What is the meaning of the following line in C. What is the order of execute it?

```
float *x,*y;
*x++=*y++
```

Can any one explain how this evaluated?

Comment: gcc says: `error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

Comment: It is fascinating or sad how many wrong answers appeared.

Comment: @wroniasty you should have made that an answer :)

Comment: @Named I was too busy compiling ;)

Comment: You can't dereference a `float`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**For the original code:**

```
x++ = y++
```

This line will never be evaluated because it is not legal C and will not be compiled. The result of `x++` is not an lvalue and is not permitted on the left side of an assignment.

**For the updated code:**

```
float x,y;
*x++ = *y++
```

This is not legal because `*` cannot be applied to a `float`.

**I will add this code:**

```
float *x, *y;
*x++ = *y++;
```

This code says:

- Let a temporary, say `float *xt`, equal `x`.
- Let a temporary, say `float *yt`, equal `y`.
- Add one to `x`.
- Add one to `y`.
- Assign `*xt = *yt`.

The actual operations may be performed in various orders, provide `xt` takes its value before `x` is updated, `yt` takes its value before `y` is updated, and `xt` and `yt` are defined before they are used.

Comment: This is the exact answer.... +1 for you sir.

Answer (score 0):

If the two variables are int (or another simple type), the original statement (`x++=y++`) is illegal.  However, in the case of pointer arithmetic, this is legal.  One way to copy a string where both `x` and `y` are `char *`, is

```
while ( *x++ = *y++ );
```

in this case, the pointer is incremented after the corresponding character is copied and the loop iterates until it encounters the end of string character (a `NULL`) in the string pointed to by `y`.

Comment: Darn, some downvote-happy dude is here. I think I know who that is, too. Anyway, there's nothing wrong with this answer, so +1.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering about it myself.  Anyway, I see that the question has been changed as well (though it is still wrong).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Can you show a declaration for `x` and `y` such that `x++ = y++` compiles? If not, then the statement that “this is legal”, even qualified with “in the case of pointer arithmetic”, is not true. A statement that “a modified statement, such as shown below, is legal” could be true. The down vote is not permanent; if the answer is edited, I will reconsider it.

Comment: Wait, the answer clarified that it should be with the pointer arithmetic and the example considered is that of a string.  It does not do x++ = y++ and so, is correct.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Not only does the answer make it abundantly clear that "this is legal" is referring to a case with pointers, it also supplies an example.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Even if `x` and `y` are pointers, such as `float *x, *y;`, `x++ = y++` is not legal. My judgement is that the use (or misuse) of the pronoun “this” is misleading and makes this answer not useful.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You seem to misunderstand the meaning of "ad hominem": my comment has been about your comment, and only about your comment. Honestly, the comments that depend on attribution of the pronoun "this" are inevitably of hair-splitting nature, which is what I tried to point out. My deleted comment has not in any way meant to disrespect or offend you personally, so I regret it if you happened to construe my comment as offensive.